# How to load Avro and store into HBase w/pig or java?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, avro

I have a file sample.avro in hdfs that I want to store into HBase (the file contains multiple entries representing multiple items I want to store in a row based on "uniqueid". If unserialized, the avro contains the following:

{
   uniqueid: 132424,
   metadata: {
      item: "Apple",
      color: "red",
      properties: ["Crispy", "Juicy"]
   },
   related: {
      class: "Fruit",
      movie: "Snow White"
   }
}

How do I get just the "metadata" object into an HBase table in Java or Pig? I've noticed this example, but it requires a csv file whereas the files I am working with have multiple lines of avro serialized files.

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar

fs -rm -r -f inputdir outputdir

A = LOAD '1.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:bytearray, f2:bytearray);
B = MAPREDUCE 'target/hbase-bulkload-avro-1.0.0-job.jar' STORE A INTO 'inputdir' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage('schema', '
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "r",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "f1",
    "type" : "bytes"
  }, {
    "name" : "f2",
    "type" : "bytes"
  } ]
}
') LOAD 'outputdir' `com.cloudera.examples.hbase.bulkimport.Driver inputdir outputdir foo`;
DUMP B;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The steps would be 1. Load the file 2. Parse the file 3. Store the result. From your question it is not entirely clear where you get stuck. Perhaps you could include the code that you have so far?